# Rails 5.0.1 - Edit route goes to /admin/moderators/edit(.:format), can't find id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby on rails 5.0.1  edit route goes to /admin/moderators/edit(.:format) no id

I click Edit on the page http://localhost:3000/admin/moderators

It will leads to the page http://localhost:3000/admin/moderators/edit.1

Then will show the error ***Couldn't find Moderator with 'id'=***

edit route shows as below:

```
edit_admin_moderators_path

GET

/admin/moderators/edit(.:format)admin/moderators#edit
```

routes.rb file:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    resource :moderators, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
end
end
```

moderators_controller.rb file:

```
class Admin::ModeratorsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @moderators = Moderator.all
  end

  def edit
    @moderator = Moderator.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
  end

end
```

show.html.erb file:

```
    <h1> Moderator's Index</h1>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>fullname</th>
    <th>username</th>
    <th>created</th>
    <th>actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <% @moderators.each do |moderator| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= moderator.fullname %></td>
    <td><%= moderator.username %></td>
    <td><%= time_ago_in_words(moderator.created_at) %> ago</td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_moderators_path(moderator) %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>

</table>
```

edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Edit Moderator</h1>


<%= form_for [:admin, @moderator] do |f| %>
<p>
  <%= f.lable :fullname %>
  <%= f.text_field :fullname %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.lable :username %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.lable :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= f.submit %>
</p>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are going with `.1`?
Typically i would expect the route to look like this: `/admin/moderators/1/edit`

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your `routes.rb` file?

Comment: @jasonkim it's part of the error he's experiencing

Comment: When you are doing a link_to a singular resource (_moderator_ in your example) instead of a collection of resources (e.g. moderators), you'll want call the path helper in its singular form, *edit_admin_moderator_path(moderator)*

Comment: @Jason Kim I don't know why it goes to .1 not /admin/moderators/1/edit. is that because the version of rails? I have no idea and hopeless. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check in your `config/routes.rb` that the route to your controller is defined like this:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :moderators, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
end
```

Note the plural `resources`. Because routes generated by the `resource` (singular) method do not accept ids (why would you need an id if there is only one thing?).

Create the link in the view like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_moderator_path(moderator) %>
```

Note the singular: It is `...moderator_path` and not `...moderators_path` for an action on a single moderator.